# How to get raw query string data and use it to build iframe source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, query-string

I have a scenario with a client where I'm trying to pass query string data from form 1 to form 2, to pre-fill the second form with contact info. Form 2 is iframed on the first form's "thank you" page.

Here's how the URL looks after a person submits the first form and is redirected to the next page...

```
http://website.com/thanks/?a=First+Last&b=name%40website.com
```

And here's how the form is initially loaded on that page, within an iframe

```
<iframe id="form2" src="http://website.com/form2" width="315px" height="340px" frameborder="0" marginheight="30" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

My current attempt at the script for this would get the query string data from the URL WITHOUT decoding it ([using an answer from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)), and then would rebuild the iframe's source with the query string data, so form 2 has query string data to pull and can be pre-filled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
} ();

window.onload = function loadSite() {
document.getElementById('form2').src = 'http://website.com/form2' + '?a=' + QueryString.a + '&b=' + QueryString.b;
}

</script>
```

This should rebuild the iframe code like so...

```
<iframe id="form2" src="http://website.com/form2/?a=First+Last&b=name%40website.com" width="315px" height="340px" frameborder="0" marginheight="30" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

But for some reason it's not working. The function to rebuild the iframe source isn't running, and I suspect it has something to do with how the script gets the query string data.

Do you see any reasons why? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you just want the querysting, why are you ripping it apart and putting it back together?

Just use

```
var qs = window.location.search;
var myUrl = "http://www.example.com" + qs;
document.getElementById('form2').src = myUrl;
```

Comment: That worked perfect and was super simple! Thanks!